# PySpark convert column with lists to boolean columns

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a PySpark DataFrame like this:

| Id | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | one,two,three |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | one,two,four,five |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | four,five |

And I am looking to convert the Z-column into separate columns, where the value of each row should be 1 or 0 based on whether or not that particular row contains the value of the column:

| Id | X | Y | one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Edit:
So far I have tried exploding the Z-column containing the list of values I would like to add as columns, but I couldn't find a way to dynamically set the resulting column name to the value of the list items.
I also tried collect the dataframe rows to loop over them and manually create a 2d-array with new columns, however this results in Spark/Databricks/the cluster crashing.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to format the sample input and output. And have you tried any specific code/method to achieve this?

Comment: I was editing over and over, converted it to a code-table now. Editing question to explain what I have tried

Comment: Do you want it as a real table format (not a code block)?

Comment: As long as visitors can understand and comprehend the table, the format does not matter to me.

Comment: You can roll it back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you followed (exploding column 'z') is the right approach. From there you can make use of `pivot()` function to convert the row values to columns. Look at the following code.

```
data = [[1,1,1,"one,two,three"],[2,1,2,"one,two,four,five"],[3,2,1,"four,five"]]
cols = ['id','x','y','z']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=cols)
df.printSchema()

#output
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |-- z: string (nullable = true)
```

- Now I converted `z` column from string to an array column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df1 = df.select('id','x','y',split(df['z'],"[,]").alias('z'))
df1.show(truncate=False)

#output
+---+---+---+----------------------+
|id |x  |y  |z                     |
+---+---+---+----------------------+
|1  |1  |1  |[one, two, three]     |
|2  |1  |2  |[one, two, four, five]|
|3  |2  |1  |[four, five]          |
+---+---+---+----------------------+
```

- On this dataframe, I exploded on column `z`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df2 = df1.select('id','x','y',explode(df1.z).alias('z'))
```

[image]

- Now, I have used `pivot()` function on `z` column after applying `groupBy()` on `id, x and y` columns. If a specific value is missing, then pivot() would insert `null`. So, I filled the null values with 0 to get the required result.

```
sol_df = df2.groupBy('id','x','y').pivot('z').count()
sol_df.fillna(0).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like I was missing how to use pivot(), because this worked wonderfully. Thanks for your time!